# Formula for all possible multiplication combinations of $k$ numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set with size $n$. For instance for size 4, $\{a,b,c,d\}$, where the elements are integers. Is there a general formula for finding all the sets of products of all combinations of 1, 2, 3, and 4 of the elements?

We can easily enumerate the possibilities by hand for a small set like this:
$$\{a, b, c, d\};\{ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd\};\{abc, abd, acd, bcd\};\{abcd\}$$

But once you start getting to $n=6$ or higher, this becomes unwieldy; calculating all 32 products is a lot, and it doubles each time.

Is there a general way to get these sets of numbers, or even sums of the sets? Or is it just something I'll need to program?

Comment: What is your goal? It's a bit strange to be interested in either these sets, or their sums. Is just their sums sufficient?

Comment: Actually, the sets themselves would be sufficient. I've since learned this is known as the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of a set, which has helped much.

Comment: @EricSnyder If you want the sets themselves, then you're stuck with the reality that there are up to $2^n$ elements. You can at least streamline the work by doing only one multiplication or division at a time, as opposed to recalculating each element individually.